# New Django Developer unable to get "Hello World" to display on website instead of the default installed successfully page

Tags: django, django-views

I am following along with a Django tutorial to create my first website.  Everything was working according to plan until I reached the step that involved the URL Patterns.  Specifically it is the include() function that made this project come off the rails.  When I reached this point in the tutorial I ran the server on my localhost.  The default Django installed successfully homepage was displayed instead of the "Hello World" text that is my tutorial index page.  I have double checked that my code matches both the tutorial that I am following as well as the official Django tutorial but my results do not change.  I have checked several solutions from Stack Overflow but have been unable to resolve this problem.

**/first_project/first_project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include('first_app.urls')),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

**first_project/first_project/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "first_app",
]
```

**/first_project/first_app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),
]
```

**first_project/first_app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

One of the suggestions on Stack Overflow was under first_project/first_project/urls.py to change the urlpatterns=[  path("", include('first_app.urls')),...]  It originally read path("first_app/", include("first_app.urls")).  The suggestion was to remove the first "first_app" and change it to a blank field "".  That did not fix the problem.

Edit- Requested project Hierarchy -
[image: Project Hierarchy]

Comment: everything seems alright, Did you make sure that all files are saved before trying to open the link?

Comment: Yes.  When I am at the localhost website and I add /first_app or /index or /first_app/index to the webaddress it gives me the django error not found page.  So something isn't working.

Comment: what do you see when you enter  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ?

Comment: "The install worked successfully! Congratulations!
You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and you have not configured any URLs."

Comment: when trying 127.0.0.1:8000/index I get the following:
"Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/index
Using the URLconf defined in first_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, index, didn’t match any of these."

This tells me Django is not seeing any of the urlpatterns that I coded.

Comment: the error when trying 127.0.0.1:8000/index  makes sense because you have not defined such a URL but the first one doesn't make sense since your default URL should be your hello world response.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. What happened when you used your original version with `path("first_app/", include("first_app.urls"))` and then went to `localhost:8000/first_app/`? Is there a difference if you don't include the trailing slash?

Comment: It hasn't worked properly with path("", include("first_app.urls")) or with path("first_app/", include("first_app.urls")).  It takes me to the following 404 error page.
"Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/first_app
Using the URLconf defined in first_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, first_app, didn’t match any of these."

Comment: The last error message is with the version that has `""`, right?

Comment: I recommend starting over. Create a new directory and follow the steps from your tutorial again. See if you can get it to work. And if you do, you can compare with your prevous attempt. I find that when I am in similar situations, this is the best way to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Thank you that is great advice.  I will begin that process today.

Comment: @Jared You should also `@` me so I get a notification when you reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the advice to start the project over and follow along with the tutorial again looking for my mistake I discovered it.

The confusion on my part was the tutorial is a few years old and utilized the "`url(r'^$'...)`" for the urlpatterns.  I incorrectly assumed that this had been simply replaced with "`path('', ...)`".  This is not a direct replacement for all instances.

I was required to use "`re_path('r^....)`" for urlpatterns that involved the "`include()`" function and other regular expressions.  Changing the code to use `re_path(...)` fixed all issues.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I'm just now getting back to this. I'm glad you found a solution that works. I wonder if there is a way do to do what you want with `path()`. If you would like me to look into it, please edit your question with the original code using the obsolete `url()` function and at me in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

go to your `/first_project/first_app/urls.py` file

and change the code to

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path("index/", views.index, name = "index"),
    ]
```

and save the file, then in your browser try to go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/
```

Comment: After making the suggested changes and ensuring that I saved the file I am taken to the Django 404 error page. 
"Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/index
Using the URLconf defined in first_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, index, didn’t match any of these."

Comment: can you provide your project hierarchy as an image or text and add it to the question

Comment: Project Hierarchy added to original post